# How to collect the Profiler data on Unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

The truth is that I have a simple tool to let the game auto run on my android phone. I want to collect the some performance data like Profiler provides, memory, draw calls, each mem allocate on each function and so on. So is there any api or tool to reach that?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Because you can go with USB Debugging and capture whatever information is useful.

Comment: you can make use of unity profiler option with development build option check

Comment: It seems that profiler can only show about 300 frames' data, but I want to collect all the data during the running. So is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, you can't save from the Profiler more than 300 frames of data.

The only way to save a stream of profiling data, is to write a class and attach the script to every game object in the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
using System.Collections;

public class ProfilerDataLogger : MonoBehaviour
{
    int frameCount = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            frameCount = 0;
            StartCoroutine(DataLogger());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DataLogger()
    {        
        while (true)
        {
            string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/profilerData" + frameCount + ".log";
            Profiler.logFile = filepath;
            Profiler.enableBinaryLog = true;
            Profiler.enabled = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                if (!Profiler.enabled)
                    Profiler.enabled = true;
            }
            frameCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can load the log files (each containing 300 frames of data) in the Profiler, or you can write a class in order to execute the loading from the Editor.